# Codename One Back to Previous Form Command Error

Tags: java, codenameone, back

I would like to access my app's native hardware back button to go to a previous form. Sounds trivial, but I am running into a series of issues, when using the approaches found around here:

```
Command back = new Command("Back") {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {

       showBack();
    }
};
```

or

```
Command back = new Command("Back") {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {

       showPreviousForm();
    }
};
```

for both the approaches I get an error message :

```
The method showBack() is undefined for the type new Command(){}
```

or

```
The method PreviousForm() is undefined for the type new Command(){}
```

Has there been a change in methods? Is there are different approach?

Thanks in advance for any response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`showBack` is a method of `Form` so this would work if the command is defined within a `Form` subclass. Otherwise you would need an instance of the form to invoke this on.

`showPreviousForm` is a custom method you would need to define to show the previous form in some way.